# rails3 doesn't load my validators in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I put EmailValidator in lib/validators/email_validator and it's not workings (I put root/lib in the load_path)

here is the code.. I put the class in module validators as the parent folder name

```
class Validators::EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
        unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@([a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i
            object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")
        end
    end
end
```

I get the error Unknown validator: 'email'

Comment: Please show us how you put `root/lib` in the load path.

Comment: config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Either put your custom validator under `config/initializers`.
2. Or add `lib/validators` to the autoload path in `config/application.rb`.

   `config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib/validators"`

Personally I would go with the second option as `lib/validators` makes for good encapsulation.

Comment: Since the OP's class is under the `Validators::` namespace, and the `lib` directory is on the autoload path by default, I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: Rails 3 no longer lazy-loads files in the lib directory, you have to add the lib directory to autoload, or require the appropriate files explicitly.

Comment: you right about the lazy_loads, but I added the general path of /lib, and the email_validator is under module validators (like the folder contain email_validator), so shouldn't it work without add another path to the config file?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd missed that detail. I'd need to look at the code for the autoloading, but I think it is non-recursive, so it wouldn't pick up files in a directory.

Comment: it will pick up files in a directory provided you stick to naming conventions (i.e. folder name = underscored module/class name)... there's no need to add every single namespace you have to the autoload paths ;)

Answer (score 10):

Since you put your custom validator in the `Validators::` in the `lib/validators`, you have to reference it with that namespace also.

```
validates :email, presence: true, :'validators/email' => true
```

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: You need this:

```
module Validators
  class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate(object, attribute, value)
        unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@([a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i
            object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")
        end
    end
  end
end

class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Validators

  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
end
```

Otherwise, you need to put your validator class under the `ActiveModel::Validations` namespace.  When you namespace a class, ActiveRecord isn't going to see it, if that namespace isn't a namespace it has already included.

Comment: I use it with the user model. here is the code---> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :name, :presence => true;
 validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true, :uniqueness => true; .tnx